# Помогите разобраться в выводе

Tags: javascript

Дорогие программисты,есть маленький кусок кода,который я,к сожалению,не понял,а именно : почему на выходе получается function, в коде нет метода 2,почему работает?

```
var arr = ["a", "b"];

arr.push(function() {
  alert( this );
})

arr[2](); // "a","b",function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нумерация в массиве начинается с нуля, а квадратные скобки говорят о том, что мы обращаемся к *элементу* массива

```
const a = [1, "2", function foo() {}, {}];
a[0]; // number
a[1]; // string
a[2]; // function
a[3]; // object
```

В вашем случае элемент ( функция ) еще и сразу же вызывается

Answer (score 1):

this внутри function - это ссылка на сам массив. В момент, когда ты вызываешь arr2 ты вызываешь функцию, помещенную внутрь массива на позицию с индексом 2. Она в свою очередь показывает тебе содержимое массива, буквы a,b и функцию на 3 позиции. Ты можешь поиграться с этим, поместив, например, внутри функции this в глобальную переменную. Например так

```
var a = 123
var arr = ["a", "b"];

arr.push(function() {
a = this;
alert( this );
})

arr[2]();
```

и посмотри, как меняется переменная a до вызова arr2 и после.